# Extract timestamp from 32-bit modbus-register

Tags: date, time, modbus-tcp

So I am trying to extract the date and time from a Modbus-device (Wetspec200).
I am using the simplyModbus software to see what is written in the registers. The manual of the device says, that the timestamp is written in the registers 1013 and 1014.[image: registers of date/time]

When I look the values in these registers I get **3** for register 1013 and **17961** for register 1014.
[image]

How exactly can I get the timestamp out of this? I tried to bring the two registers together. The lower register represents the first 16 bit and the higher register represents the last 16 bits. So the value 3 is 00000000 00000011 in binary and 17961 is 01000110 00101001.
So merged together it would become 00000000 00000011 01000110 00101001. But that doesnt make any sense to me. Do you have any idea how I could get the date/time from these two registers?

There was a similar post about the same problem, but the answer was not right for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the manual? As far as modbus does not specify any requirements for timestamp format, everyone goes his own way.

If it is not written in manual, then try using its own software to extract data from device, then look (or share) the time stamp, shown in a software and try to find how it corresponds to binary value (usually it is easy).

As far as we have only 18 non-zero bits I guess it stores only delta in seconds (or minutes) from some setpoint, which is stored separately in another register. This is a common practice for metering devices

Answer (score 1):

May be it is a Unix timestamp?
Bringing the two registers together and converting due to Unix format gives: 04/20/2007 @ 6:01pm (UTC).